# Prove that $2 ^ {((\log n)^2) }= n \log n$

Tags: logarithms

I've let $y = 2 ^ {((\log n)^2)}$ and arrive at $\log_2 y = (\log n)(\log n)$, but am unsure how to proceed from here. Help will be appreciated thank you!

Comment: try $n=1$ first. You obtain $2^0=1\cdot0$ i.e. $1=0$. From here you could proceed to prove anything, by a contradiction.

Comment: Is that log base 2 or some other base.

Answer (score 0):

They are not equal.

$$2^{\log^2(n)}\neq n\cdot\log(n)$$

Substituting $n$ for $1$:

$$\begin{align}
& 2^{\log^2(1)}\neq1\cdot\log(1) \\
\implies& 1\neq0 \\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $n$ is a natural number and the logs are $2$-based, your expression is wrong:
$$2^{(\log n)^2} =2^{(\log n)(\log n)} = (2^{\log n})^{\log n} =n^{\log n} \neq n\log n.$$

Comment: I have never encountered the assumption that $\log\equiv\log_2$. I've only seen $\log\equiv\log_{10}$ and $\log\equiv\log_e$.

Comment: @ProtectedSource they use $\log$ for $\log_2$ in computer science https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm and http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/311366-in-computer-science-does-log-n-automatically-imply-base-2/